# Nodejs https combined with cpanel

Tags: node.js, ssl, cpanel

I am trying to get https working on my nodejs server like so:

```
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('server.key', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('server.crt', 'utf8');

var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
var app = express();

var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

httpServer.listen(8080, ()=> {
    console.log('Server started and listening on port 8080...')
});
httpsServer.listen(8443, ()=>{
    console.log('Server started and listening on port 8443...')
});
```

When I run the server only the http url is working, the https gets timed out.
any idea why this is happening?

I am used to work with cpanel, so I setup the ssl cert on there already, but when it comes to node, I am hitting a wall.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem was the port wasn't forwarded.

Comment: Could you tell me how do you forwarded the port?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there's something wrong with your ssl files, You need to give certificate file and private key while creating https server like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

// This line is from the Node.js HTTPS documentation.
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-cert.cert')
};

// Create a service (the app object is just a callback).
var app = express();

// Create an HTTP service.
http.createServer(app).listen(80);
// Create an HTTPS service identical to the HTTP service.
https.createServer(options, app).listen(443);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: this is exactly what I did.

Comment: can't I get cpanel to handle the ssl files?